# MongoDB Sub-Docs and Population References - "E11000 duplicate key error collection"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB library called **ecommerce**, which has collections of *products*, *users*, *carts*, and *orders*. I am still building some of the endpoints, but right now I am getting an error I can't seem to solve.

When I try to add a user, the response says: **"E11000 duplicate key error collection: ecommerce.users index: product.title_1 dup key: { : null }"**

**User Model** - Note that *cart* uses *CartSchema*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var cartSchema = require('./cartSchema');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true },
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, index: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  cart: [cartSchema],
  orders: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**Cart Schema** - Note that *product* uses ref to *Product* model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Product = require('./productModel');

module.exports = new Schema({
  products: [{
    product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, min: 1 }
  }],
});
```

**Product Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

Products I currently have in the database (notice every one has a unique title):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57104fdfa2c2256e45744706"),
    "title" : "Booze",
    "description" : "Goes down smooth",
    "price" : 16,
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57105038f560607f45b05888"),
    "title" : "Woody",
    "description" : "Sheriff over toys",
    "price" : 5,
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571181a12df983d208f4600b"),
    "title" : "Heart",
    "description" : "The love of your life",
    "price" : 68,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The first user saves just fine:

```
{
    "username" : "hman",
    "password" : "henry123456",
    "email" : "henry@gmail.com",
    "cart" : {
        "products": [{
            "product" : "57104fdfa2c2256e45744706",
            "quantity" : 1
        }]
    }
}
```

It's when I try to save a 2nd user...

```
{
    "username" : "toystorylover95",
    "password" : "woody123",
    "email" : "woody@toystory.com",
    "cart" : {
        "products": [{
            "product" : "57105038f560607f45b05888",
            "quantity" : 20
        }]
    }
}
```

... that I get the error:

```
{
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 0,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: ecommerce.users index: product.title_1 dup key: { : null }",
  "op": {
    "username": "woody-wood",
    "password": "woody123",
    "email": "woody@woody.com",
    "_id": "5713af5efd626d381700437f",
    "orders": [],
    "cart": [
      {
        "_id": "5713af5efd626d3817004380",
        "products": [
          {
            "product": "57105038f560607f45b05888",
            "quantity": 20,
            "_id": "5713af5efd626d3817004381"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here's the function being called at the /users endpoint, if it helps:

```
function(req, res) {
  User.create(req.body, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(result);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: the title for both of them is `null`. That's why it's giving the duplicate key error.

Comment: Moreover, you created a "unique" index in a place that you should not have. `ecommerce.users index: product.title_1` says you created the index on the `"users"` collection, when in fact the actual data is in the `"products"` collection. Hence why this is considered `null` in both cases since `"users"` has no such property of `"product.title"`. Remove the erroneous index on the `"users"` collection. `db.users.dropIndex({ "product.title": 1 })` and this resolves the problem.

Comment: I ran the command you gave, Neil, and it worked. I don't understand why, but thank you! Looks like I need to learn about indexing a bit more.